# How to get all documents snapshot that have the same id in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get all documents snaps[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb9fQ.png)hot by searching by user id

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat')
          .where('users.id', arrayContains: '1')
          .get();